# send multiple emails using custom job in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, queue, jobs

I tried to create a job in order to send emails to all users in the database I have done everything and connected successfully with Mailtrip but still have a problem : (Failed) when implementing the command:

```
PHP artisan queue:work
```

this is my ProductEmail class:

```
class ProductMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $product;
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Product $product, User $user)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->product->name)
        ->view('email.product');
    }
}
```

and i have created the view for it>>>>

and here the job class

```
class NotifyUsersForProduct implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

     public $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->$product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $users->map(function(User $user){
                Mail::to($user)->send(new ProductMail($this->product, $user));
        });
    }
}
```

and here i have use it

```
try {
             $product = Product::create([
                  'name' => $request->input('name'),
                  'price' => $request->input('price'),
                  'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
                  'user_id' => Auth::id(),
             ]);

        NotifyUsersForProduct::dispatch($product);
```

the error message:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function __construct(Product $product)
{
    $this->$product = $product;
}
```

This should be:

```
 public function __construct(Product $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;
}
```

Remove $
and also i recommend to do this but not necessary:

```
 public function handle()
{
    $users = User::all();
    foreach($users as $user){
            Mail::to($user)->send(new ProductMail($this->product, $user));
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Taht should do it. gl

Comment: unfortunately, same problem

Comment: $this->$product = $product should be $this->product = $product

Comment: yes yes, just a mistake !!!!!!, just add this in your answer to accept it>>>> because I don't need to change anything except remove $

Comment: Already put it on my Answer, please accept it. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

You are facing a failed Job because instant send invokes mail please try the below code to i make some corrections to solve your problem add delay method

```
class NotifyUsersForProduct implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->$product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($user)->send(new ProductMail($this->product, $user));
    }

    public function test(){
        $delay = 30;
         try {
                 $product = Product::create([
                      'name' => $request->input('name'),
                      'price' => $request->input('price'),
                      'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
                      'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                 ]);
                $users = User::all(); // move this code to controller 
                
                foreach ($users as  $user) {
                   
                 
                    NotifyUsersForProduct::dispatch($product)->delay($delay);
                    $delay +=30;
                }

                  
        }catch(Exception $exception){

        }
    }
}
```